# PHP var_dump only outputting value of bottom checkbox

Tags: php, forms, post, input, var-dump

Hi and thanks for reading my question. I am using a simple form to get some input :

```
<p>Select your favorite two countries below:</p>

<form id="world" name="world" action="/order.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="countries" value="USA" /> USA<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="countries" value="Canada" /> Canada<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="countries" value="Japan" /> Japan<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="countries" value="China" /> China<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="countries" value="France" /> France<br />
<input type="submit" value="Order">
</form>
```

I want to make sure order.php is geting all of the choices selected, so order.php only contains the following code :

```
<pre>
<?php var_dump($_POST);?>
</pre>
```

Unfortunately, it is only outputting whatevre is the bottom-most checkbox that is checked.

The output is like this :

array(1) {
  ["countries"]=>
  string(6) "Canada"
}

If i try the following code for output :

```
<?php
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$post_data){
        echo "You posted:" . $key . " = " . $post_data . "<br>";
    }
?>
```

I get this output :

You posted:countries = Canada

Can anyone tell me where i am going wrong and how i can retrieve all of the data, for every box that is ticked ?

Thank you.

Comment: use `name="countries[]"` it will submit array of values in `$_POST['countries']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p>Select your favorite two countries below:</p>

<form id="world" name="world" action="/order.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="countries[]" value="USA" /> USA<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="countries[]" value="Canada" /> Canada<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="countries[]" value="Japan" /> Japan<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="countries[]" value="China" /> China<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="countries[]" value="France" /> France<br />
<input type="submit" value="Order">
</form>
```

Change it to above, this will store all your checkboxes results for you!

Comment: Thank you Michael and Mark B. Unfortunately, using the array notation, the script i am using to check that only a certain number of boxes are ticked will not work. The script is called checkboxlimit and is called like this : <script type="text/javascript">
checkboxlimit(document.forms.world.countries, 2)
</script>

Comment: sure it will. `if (count($_POST['countries']) > 5) { die("Too many"); }`. javascript won't care about the `[]`. it's just some extra characters in the name.

Comment: This is the script that checks the limits, owuld i be able to change all references to checkgroup to an array ? I've never learned JS : 'function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit){
 var checkgroup=checkgroup
 var limit=limit
 for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++){
  checkgroup[i].onclick=function(){
  var checkedcount=0
  for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++)
   checkedcount+=(checkgroup[i].checked)? 1 : 0
  if (checkedcount>limit){
   alert("You can only select a maximum of "+limit+" checkboxes")
   this.checked=false
   }
  }
 }
}'

Comment: Thanks Mark B. That line of code is PHP to check the limits is it? If so then i don't need the JS ? The JS doesn't work now that i've changed the form to array notation.

Comment: You can check it with this line on the nextpage (order.php in your case)

Answer (score 2):

You gave the same `name` to your checkboxes, and PHP will overwrite previously parsed `name` submissions with the current value. You need to use the array-notation hack:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="countries[]" value="Canada" /> Canada<br />
                                      ^^
```

which then makes `$_POST['countries']` an array of all the values submitted.

```
echo "You posted: " . implode(',', $_POST['countries']);
```